# How do you put heading on the same line in HTML

Tags: html, xhtml, html5-canvas

How do you put 3 heading on the same line? 
So it looks like...

Heading 1                  Heading 2              Heading 3

Comment: using CSS or tables should work

Comment: do you want use canvas? I see the tag canvas.

Comment: You need to accept an answer.

Answer (score 3):

Use the css display property `inline-block`

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nze65jkk/

Answer (score 0):

You can use css to edit h1 style:

HTML

```
<h1>Something</h1>
<h2>Something</h2>
<h3>Something more</h3>
```

CSS

```
h1, h2, h3 {
  display: inline; /* You can use inline-block too */
  padding: 0 5px; /* To give space among h* tags */
}
```